# how to get value in textview in method onItemClickListener in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, textview, onitemclicklistener

This is the code of my main page:

```
package com.buanasoft.toko;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
     
    public class f_penjualan extends Activity  {
       private long rowID;
       private TextView nm_barangTv;
       private TextView hargaTv;
       private TextView h_jualTv;
       private TextView satuanTv;
       private TextView stokTv;
        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.f_penjualan);
 
        setUpViews();
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          rowID = extras.getLong(f_data.ROW_ID); 
        
        Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pilih);
        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), daftar_barang.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        
    }

       private void setUpViews() {
           nm_barangTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namaBarangText);
           hargaTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hargaBarangText);
           h_jualTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hargaJualText);
           satuanTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.satuanText);
           stokTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stokText);   
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume()
       {
          super.onResume();
          new LoadBarang().execute(rowID);
       } 
       
       private class LoadBarang extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
       {
          DBCon_barang dbCon_barang = new DBCon_barang(f_penjualan.this);
          
          @Override
          protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
          {
             dbCon_barang.open();
             return dbCon_barang.getOneBarang(params[0]);
          } 

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
          {
             super.onPostExecute(result);   
             result.moveToFirst();
             // get the column index for each data item
             int nm_barangIndex = result.getColumnIndex("nm_barang");
             int hargaIndex = result.getColumnIndex("harga");
             int h_jualIndex = result.getColumnIndex("h_jual");
             int satuanIndex = result.getColumnIndex("satuan");
             int stokIndex = result.getColumnIndex("stok");
             nm_barangTv.setText(result.getString(nm_barangIndex));
             hargaTv.setText(result.getString(hargaIndex));
             h_jualTv.setText(result.getString(h_jualIndex));
             satuanTv.setText(result.getString(satuanIndex));
             stokTv.setText(result.getString(stokIndex));
             result.close();
             dbCon_barang.close();
          }
       } 

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
       {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.det_data_menu, menu);
          return true;
       }
       
       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
          switch (item.getItemId())
          {
             case R.id.editItem:
                Intent addEditBarang =
                   new Intent(this, AddEditBarang.class);
                
                addEditBarang.putExtra(f_data.ROW_ID, rowID);
                addEditBarang.putExtra("nm_barang", nm_barangTv.getText());
                addEditBarang.putExtra("harga", hargaTv.getText());
                addEditBarang.putExtra("h_jual", h_jualTv.getText());
                addEditBarang.putExtra("satuan", satuanTv.getText());
                addEditBarang.putExtra("stok", stokTv.getText());
               
                startActivity(addEditBarang); 
                return true;
                
             case R.id.deleteItem:
                deleteBarang();
                return true;
                
             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          } 
       }
       
       private void deleteBarang()
       {
         
          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(f_penjualan.this);

          alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
          alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

          alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                {
                   final DBCon_barang dbCon_barang = 
                      new DBCon_barang (f_penjualan.this);

                   AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                      new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                      {
                         @Override
                         protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                         {
                            dbCon_barang.deleteBarang(params[0]); 
                            return null;
                         } 
                         
                         @Override
                         protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                         {
                            finish(); 
                         }
                      };

                   deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
                }
             }
          );
          
          alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
       }
    }
```

and this is the code from my second activity

```
    public class daftar_barang extends ListActivity {
         public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
         private ListView conListView;
        

    private CursorAdapter conAdapter;
       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        
       ////script untuk memampilkan daftar barang & menu
        conListView=getListView();
        conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);
        
        // mengisi value di TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "nm_barang" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.daftar_barang };
        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(daftar_barang.this, R.layout.daftar_barang, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
        
        
    }
     
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
       super.onResume();  
       new GetData().execute((Object[]) null);
     } 
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
       Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();
       
       if (cursor != null) 
          cursor.deactivate();
       
       conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
       super.onStop();
    }    
    
  
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
    {
       DBCon_barang dbConnector = new DBCon_barang(daftar_barang.this);

       @Override
       protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
       {
          dbConnector.open();
          return dbConnector.getAllBarang(); 
       } 
       
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
       {
          conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
          dbConnector.close();
       } 
    } 
    
    
    //fungsi untuk melihat detail barang
    OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
       {         
          Intent viewCon = new Intent(daftar_barang.this,f_penjualan.class);
          viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
          startActivity(viewCon);
       }
    };    
    
}
```

I want to display the data item from my second activity to first activity.
So by the time I get into the second activity and I click on one of the data in the second activity, he will be on show to the first activity.

There is no error warning, but after building my application some errors occurred when I open the activity.

Comment: is it `rowID` you trying to pass ? Please Improve your post, logcat error, which line etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `onCreate()` of the first activity. You have this code:

```
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(f_data.ROW_ID);
```

When your activity is first launched it won't contain any extras, so the call to `getIntent().getExtras()` will return `null`. The next statement will then throw a `NullPointerException`. You need to check for `extras == null` before calling `getLong()` on it.